# Subcoalgebra generated by an element

Tags: quaternions, dual-spaces, coalgebras

Let $(A, \Delta, \epsilon)$ be a coalgebra and $f\in A$. What is the subcoalgebra generated by $f$ like?

For example, if $A$ is the dual of the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ (which is $\mathbb{R}$-algebra with the usual product and $u(1)=1$) and $f$ is the linear functional that takes $1$ to $1$ and $i, j, k$ to $0$.

My target is actually to find an element of $A=\mathbb{H}^*$ that is cocommutative but such that the subcoalgebra generated by it isn't cocommutative. But I don't know where to begin to come up with an $f$, since I don't know how the generated subcoalgebra looks like. I know that the comultiplication is

$$\Delta f(x \otimes y) = f(xy)$$

and to be cocommutative means $f(xy) = f(yx)$, right?

I think the only cocommutative $f$ is the one I mentioned (and its multiples), since $f(ij) = f(ji) \implies f(k)=f(-k) \implies f(k)=0$ and similarly for the others.

**EDIT**: So, $A = \mathbb{H}^*$ has the basis $1^*, i^*, j^*, k^*$ and "my $f$" is $1^*$. Now

$$\Delta 1^* (x \otimes y) = 1^*(x\otimes y) = \text{ the component of 1 in the product }xy \\= (1^*\otimes 1^* - i^*\otimes i^* - j^*\otimes j^* - k^*\otimes k^* )(x\otimes y)$$.

And I now realize that of course the subcoalgra generated by a set $S$ must be the smallest subcoalgebra containing that set(?). So let $D\subset A$ be a subcoalgebra with $1^* \in D$. It's a subcoalgebra so $\Delta(D) \subset D\otimes D$. Hence

$$1^*\otimes 1^* - i^*\otimes i^* - j^*\otimes j^* - k^*\otimes k^*  \in D\otimes D$$

But where to go from here? Do we see that all $i, j, k$ must belong to $D$? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra.
If $I$ is a two-sided ideal in $A$ then the orthogonal
$$
  I^\perp
  =
  \{
    \alpha \in A^*
  \mid
    \text{$\alpha(x) = 0$ for every $x \in I$}
  \}
$$
is a subcoalgebra of $A$, and if $C$ is a subcoalgebra of $A$ then its orthogonal
$$
  C^\perp
  =
  \{
    x \in A
  \mid
    \text{$\alpha(x) =  0$ for every $\alpha \in C$}
  \}
$$
is a two-sided ideal in $A$.
If $A$ is finite dimensional then these constructions are mutually inverse and therefore give a one-to-one correspondence between the two-sided ideals in $A$ and the subcoalgebras of $A^*$.

The quaternions are a skew-field and thus admit only the two trivial ideals $0$ and $\mathbb{H}$.
Hence $\mathbb{H}^*$ admits only $0^\perp = \mathbb{H}^*$ and $\mathbb{H}^\perp = 0$ as subcoalgebras.
Thus every nonzero element of $\mathbb{H}^*$ generates the whole coalgebra.

(This is taken from Sweedler’s *Hopf Algebras*, Proposition 1.43 and pages 63-64.)

---

You’re right that the cocommutativity of an element $f \in \mathbb{H}^*$ means that $f(xy) = f(yx)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{H}$.
Indeed, if we identify $\mathbb{H}^* \otimes \mathbb{H}^*$ with $(\mathbb{H} \otimes \mathbb{H})^*$ then the cocommutativity of $f$ means
$$
 \Delta(f)(x \otimes y)
 \overset{!}{=}
 \Delta(f)(y \otimes x) \,.
$$
Then also $\Delta = m^*$ for the multiplication $m \colon \mathbb{H} \otimes \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$, and we find that
$$
  f(xy) \overset{!}{=} f(yx) \,.
  \tag{$\ast$}
$$

You’re also right that the only possible $f$ is up to scalar multiple the one you give (with $f(1) = 1$ and $f(i) = f(j) = f(k) = 0$).
One can make your argument a bit less ad-hoc by observing that $(\ast)$ is equivalent to
$$
  f(xy - yx) \overset{!}{=} 0 \,,
$$
which means that $f$ must vanish on the subspace
$$
  \langle
    xy - yx
  \mid
   x, y \in \mathbb{H}
  \rangle \,.
$$
One can now check that this subspace is generated by $i$,$j$,$k$, giving again your result.
(It sufficies to consider for $x$ and $y$ basis vectors, and the basis vector $1$ can be ignored.
It now sufficies to consider the cases $(x,y) = (i,j), (i,k), (j,k)$, which give the vector space generators $\pm 2k$, $\pm 2j$, $\pm 2i$.)

---

There is also a canonical way to construct for any finite dimensional $k$-algebra $A$ with $\operatorname{char}(k) \nmid \dim(A)$ some nonzero cocommutative element $f \in A^*$:
Every element $a \in A$ gives rise to an endomorphism $L_a \colon A \to A$ given by $L_a(x) = ax$.
Then $f(a) := \operatorname{tr}(L_a)$ satisfies
$$
  f(ab)
  =
  \operatorname{tr}(L_{ab})
  =
  \operatorname{tr}(L_a L_b)
  =
  \operatorname{tr}(L_b L_a)
  =
  \operatorname{tr}(L_{ba})
  =
  f(ba) \,,
$$
and $f$ is nonzero because $f(1) = \operatorname{tr}(L_1) = \operatorname{tr}(\mathrm{id}_A) = \dim(A) \neq 0$.
For $A = \mathbb{H}$ this gives $f(i) = f(j) = f(k) = 0$ and $f(1) = 4$.

(This is again taken from Sweedler’s *Hopf Algebras*, pages 63-64.)